# CMake cross compiling for old GNU/Linux 2.0.0 VortexDX architecture

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, g++, cross-compiling

I need to cross compile C++ software to an old GNU/Linux 2.0.0 architecture running on an embedded Vortex86DX processor.

I got that info from a native executable from this hardware:

```
$ file testio

testio: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, not stripped
```

What would be the toolchain configuration in that case ?

```
# the name of the target operating system
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

# Which compilers to use for C and C++
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/???)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/???)
```

I´m running Ubuntu 15.10 with gcc-multilib installed.